# Is it possible to delete a chat conversation?

Tags: support, chat

I posted some sensitive information, and now I want to delete the chat conversation so it isn't public. Is there way I can remove that information? It's very urgent!

Comment: Rule of thumb... don't post sensitive information...

Comment: @MarcGravell Sometimes it is not intended.

Answer (score 7):

Flagging is usually the best option, although there are not always moderators present on https://chat.stackoverflow.com so it could take a little while. I've deleted the flagged messages.

Answer (score 2):

Email the Team at team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: i mailed them an hour ago,but not deleted

Comment: @pleasedeleteme They receive a lot of mail, and they can take up to 48 hours to reply. Alternatively flag the message in chat and ask a mod to delete it.